# Why is setTimeout not working with .hover()?

Tags: jquery, hover, hoverintent

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/yL1uu0hv/

I'm trying to create a simple hoverintent using setTimeout. I'm not sure what the problem is with the provided code. If I comment out `hovertimer = setTimeout(function(){` and `}, 500);` then the addClass I'm using works. If the aforementioned items are active (not commented out), addClass doesn't work.

I'm also getting some kind of error due to the syntax of `$('ul#megamenulist li').each($(this).addClass(opts.mmactiveclass.mmclassname));` and it keeps bubbling even with doing nothing.

What's supposed to happen is that after X milliseconds of hovering over the item, the class 'active' is supposed to be added to the hovered 'li' tag. If not hovered over for X milliseconds or longer, 'active' is not added. And, if 'active' is added, on mouseleave the class 'active' should be removed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('ul#megamenulist li').hover(
            function(){
                console.log('over');
                //hovertimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('ul#megamenulist li').each($(this).addClass('active'));
                //}, 500);

            },
            function(){
                console.log('off');
                clearTimeout(hovertimer);
                $('ul#megamenulist li').removeClass('active');
            }
        );
});


<div id="megamenunav">
    <ul id="megamenulist">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Explore</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Develop</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Engage</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Shop</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the context inside `setTimeout` function (`this` keyword) is global `window` object. The simplest fix for this is to save reference to `ul#megamenulist li` element in variable and use it inside `setTimeout`.

Correct code:

```
var $li = $('ul#megamenulist li').hover(
    function () {
        var self = this;
        hovertimer = setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).addClass('active');
        }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        clearTimeout(hovertimer);
        $li.removeClass('active');
    }
);
```

Also it's a good practice to cache jQuery collections to avoid repetitive DOM queries. For example you can cache it like in the code above, since `hover` returns a collection.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yL1uu0hv/2/

Comment: Amazing. Thank you dfsq. It's been driving me crazy trying to figure out why setTimeout was not working. You just got my vote and the checkmark!

Comment: Thank you! Just remember that inside `setTimeout` and `setInterval` the context `this` is always global object `window`.

Comment: Will do - thanks for pointing that out to me. I'm still learning about `this` and it's uses. It's sometimes easy for me to understand and use, and sometimes it causes problems for me.